# Getting group name using gdata api

Tags: python, gdata

I am trying to access the group name of all entries in my contact list. How can I access the details of a group given the href link?

This is the current output:

```
9 Albert Gandhi 2011-03-07T09:48:19.824Z
    I was thrown out of college for cheating on the metaphysics exam; I looked into the soul of the boy sitting next to me.
    albert.gandhi@company1.net
    Member of group: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/blah.blah%40blah.com/base/4c8d4c8d8d218d21
```

But I would like something like this:

```
9 Albert Gandhi 2011-03-07T09:48:19.824Z
    I was thrown out of college for cheating on the metaphysics exam; I looked into the soul of the boy sitting next to me.
    albert.gandhi@company1.net
    Member of group: GroupName
```

Below is the code I am using to list the contact feed (taken mainly from the examples provided with the API)

```
  def PrintFeed(self, feed, ctr=0):
    """Prints out the contents of a feed to the console.

    Args:
      feed: A gdata.contacts.ContactsFeed instance.
      ctr: [int] The number of entries in this feed previously printed. This
          allows continuous entry numbers when paging through a feed.

    Returns:
      The number of entries printed, including those previously printed as
      specified in ctr. This is for passing as an argument to ctr on
      successive calls to this method.

    """
    if not feed.entry:
      print '\nNo entries in feed.\n'
      return 0
    for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
      print '\n%s %s %s' % (ctr+i+1, entry.title.text, entry.updated.text)
      if entry.content:
        print '    %s' % (entry.content.text)
      for email in entry.email:
        if email.primary and email.primary == 'true':
          print '    %s' % (email.address)
      # Show the contact groups that this contact is a member of.
      for group in entry.group_membership_info:
        print '    Member of group: %s' % (group.href)
      # Display extended properties.
      for extended_property in entry.extended_property:
        if extended_property.value:
          value = extended_property.value
        else:
          value = extended_property.GetXmlBlobString()
        print '    Extended Property %s: %s' % (extended_property.name, value)
    return len(feed.entry) + ctr
```

Comment: @gonvaled From where does come **'GroupName'** we see in what you show as the string you want as a result for 'Member of Group:' ? http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/blah.blah%40blah.com/base/4c8d4c8d8d218d21 is **group.href** , as far as I undesratnd. So you must find the attribute of group that will give the GroupName . What else ??

Comment: GroupName is just a placeholder. There should go the real group name, like Friends, Coworkers, or any custom defined group name. The problem is that I do not know how to access that information starting with the href of the group.

Comment: @gonvaled We cannot know more. I tried the address, the result is _Authorization required Error 401_ It seems it is a private database or site. How do you want people to be able to obtain information from a private place ?

Comment: You will not be able to access that address, since it is obfuscated - it is just an example. The request should be performed in a gdata api authentication context. This should return detailed information about the group, but I do not know how to implement this.

Comment: @gonvaled So your code is of no utility. Your question is about the functioning of gdata. I didn't notice the name gdata in your code, although it is in it. Is gdata  standing for Google Data ?

Comment: Yes, gdata is the google data api. My code needs to be modified in order to use the href related to a given contact group to get detailed information about that contact. I would like to know how to implement this.

Comment: @gonvaled well, isn't the _modus operandi_ to obtain the group to be searched in the documentation of the API ?

Comment: I have not found that information in the api documentation. That is why I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, you can find a solution to this issue [here](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/community/forum.html?place=topic/google-contacts-api/KrUWZP9F78A/discussion)